# is there a `eapply`-like tactic that works on `exists` goals in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I have the following during a proof where the goal is an existential, and the target property is one of the assumptions.

```
H : x ==> y
...
______________________________________(1/2)
exists t : tm, x ==> t
```

I know I can do `exists y. apply H.` to prove the current goal, but I am wondering if there is a more intelligent tactic that can use the assumption directly to prove the existential goal here, like `eapply H`?

Since this is one unification away, it would be nice not having to write the `X` part in `exists X.`.

If such a tactic does not exist, how do I write one?

Comment: what is `eapply`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exists such a tactic and it is called `eexists`.
It does exactly what you seem to expect.

https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic23

---

Example use:

```
Variable T : Type.
Variable R : T -> T -> Prop.

Theorem test : forall x y, R x y -> exists t, R x t.
Proof.
  intros. eexists. apply H.
Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that `eexists` is the same with `exists`. I still have to do `eexists y. apply H`, and need to figure out the unification, i.e. `y` myself. It would be nice if I can do something like `eexists H.` or even just `eassumption` to complete the unification.

Comment: @tinlyx I added an example, you don't need to specify `y`.

Comment: Thanks. An extra question. Is there a way to avoid the `apply H` part? I can imagine something like `eassumption` that tries `apply` on every assumption. I tried `assumption` and got `Error: No such assumption.`

Comment: @tinlyx `eexists. eassumption.` works perfectly for the above example. `eauto.` works too, btw.