# What is a good example of a simple proof in Coq where the conclusion has a existential quantifier?

Tags: coq

I wanted to see a few hands on examples of Coq proofs of the form:

```
\exists A(x1,...,xn)
```

essentially where the Goal had an existential quantifier. I was having issues manipulating the goal in meaningful ways to make progress in my proof and wanted to see a few examples of common tactics to manipulate.

What are some good existential quantifiers examples in Coq to prove?

---

My specific example I had:

```
Theorem Big_Small_ForwardImpl   :
  forall (P : Program) (S' : State),
    (BigStepR (B_PgmConf P) (B_StateConf S')) -> (ConfigEquivR (S_PgmConf P) (S_BlkConf EmptyBlk S')).
Proof.
  intros.
  induction P.
  unfold ConfigEquivR.
  refine (ex_intro _ _ _) .
```

my context and goals was:

```
1 subgoal
l : list string
s : Statement
S' : State
H : BigStepR (B_PgmConf (Pgm l s)) (B_StateConf S')
______________________________________(1/1)
exists N : nat, NSmallSteps N (S_PgmConf (Pgm l s)) (S_BlkConf EmptyBlk S')
```

but then changed to:

```
1 subgoal
l : list string
s : Statement
S' : State
H : BigStepR (B_PgmConf (Pgm l s)) (B_StateConf S')
______________________________________(1/1)
NSmallSteps ?Goal (S_PgmConf (Pgm l s)) (S_BlkConf EmptyBlk S')
```

after using the `refine (ex_intro _ _ _)` tactic. Since I am not sure what is going on I was hoping some simpler examples could show me how to manipulate existential quantifiers in my Coq goal.

---

helpful comment:

> The ?Goal was introduced by Coq as a placeholder for some N that will have to be deduced later in the proof.

Comment: The `?Goal` was introduced by Coq as a placeholder for some `N` that will have to be deduced later in the proof. You can see the same behavior when using the `eexists` tactic.

Comment: @J-M.Gorius honestly, I have no idea how one comes up with such a `N`, the reason I was thinking that looking for a simpler example first would be easier than the one I am actually working on...

Comment: @J-M.Gorius thanks! I didn't know thats what it stood for.

Comment: It is often possible for Coq to automatically deduce a value for `?Goal` as the proof goes on. You can continue the proof as if `?Goal` was a well-defined value and let Coq do the "dirty work" behind the scenes.

Comment: @J-M.Gorius perhaps this is why I need a simpler concrete example to work through this. I just can't imagine right now what I can even do to the goal...not sure if its because its a quantifier example or what is getting me stuck...

Comment: I added an example in the form of an answer as it would not fit in a comment.

Comment: @J-M.Gorius I went through the `eexists` documentation and it doesn't really make sense to me. What is that doing?

Comment: This might be relevant for a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example is based on the code provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34220121/6674126).

Suppose we have a type `T` and a binary relation `R` on elements of type `T`. For the purpose of this example, we can define those as follows.

```
Variable T : Type.
Variable R : T -> T -> Prop.
```

Let us prove the following simple theorem.

```
Theorem test : forall x y, R x y -> exists t, R x t.
```

Here is a possible solution.

```
Proof.
  intros. exists y. apply H.
Qed.
```

Instead of explicitly specifying that `y` is the element we are looking for, we can rely on Coq's powerful automatic proof mechanisms in order to automatically deduce which variable satisfies `R x t`:

```
Proof.
  intros.
  eexists. (* Introduce a temporary placeholder of the form ?t *)
  apply H. (* Coq can deduce from the hypothesis H that ?t must be y *)
Qed.
```

There exist numerous tactics that make ise of the same automated deduction mechanisms, such as `eexists`, `eapply`, `eauto`, etc.

Note that their names often correspond to usual tactics prefixed with an `e`.

Comment: how do you know to use `eexists` and not some other `eTACTIC`?

Comment: The reasoning behind using `eexists` might be as follows: "I know that I have to prove that there *exists* some `t` satisfying `R x t`, but it may be cumbersome to specify it. I will let Coq introduce a temporary existential variable and let it do the work." In essence, I *know* that such a `t` has to exist, but I do not bother explicitly specifying it. I specifically use `eexists` because what I want to do is prove the *existence* of `t`.